# MaxMSP/Arcade Button Responding Incorrectly with HI Objject

Tags: max-msp-jitter

I'm linking an arcade button connected to a USB encoder with a Max patch. The button is behaving strangely. Here's what happens:

- I have the button mapped to the `a` key. When Max is open, this functionality breaks. Even outside of Max. Even once I close Max, I need to remap the key. I'm not using MAME or anything like that; just JoytoKey for the mapping.
- This issue is negated partially through use of the `HI`object. Max recognizes the button and I can use it, however it's not functioning as an on/off. Rather a bang is sent on button press *and* release. How do I make the button work normally (send a single bang on press, and none on release)?

Here's my patch, if it helps. I don't know how useful it is without my video files:

```
<pre><code>
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
2245.3oc6cszbjpaEdsmpl+CTr1gB8hGYY1jJYaRVMUptvzx1ZtzPGdX6I2J
+2i3YyCoF0.M8hqbMi6FjP5b9zQe5bPvw+92+1Sluj7EMyz3Oa7Cimd524m4
opyUdlmZOwSlmB9JLJHqphlEmnwElO2TzGAowAmnBJIt3DKNhlWcUf1ydNHk
W8bZ5AZbvKQzAExxomp6j+JMllxBMLL9W+i+hgweO4WY4rveyvneymTj219n
tl3X00m7xO+S.+tJWWy7eclVqqlr3bymMLq9uw+9hvkG9NK9sCozv75Zhv9V
DhM+G.B.P1Pf+yF.Hwxl+gKn7CHzx9RajE7A83gf77T1KE4zKeKqATaQ0RrK
pfl7Z646JnOJEkD+lX.dP0NwGhJqhsnBydOIMWgFge9SM3ib7uSSGbosPKro
r+22+V82Z+Rym7OdVYKsSzrrf2ncih4zuxaJPlcFTr4APj4AQt4wBrIbsKsE
P9WrHVrdGS+jKfSU62YyL4ZnRCEnzH45bDKKegyG78rP9k+f7g1HnC.xw.d8
taHwOY4VexhOl7ow4nfeUJ5GYYm6p34TZFMNOHmkDeHhESCSJhyGPTLnJWzO
Hvxydj5g8qFacvk+lX2e19MMNzuKkZUBskOD8RP7ayODAvdkPuCeTojjBh1.
SxH1GTqJ3WDw+zRkft.WGqJCEWaWejKDa6H15AWg0.Rer9TxQZeNNy7zf3LV
KZBWwBOqY.C3cEdj4GrVChbOWqYxXpv0a.yudy0andq4vEQPIfw+DtmKyHij
IiFYPlyhF54Nkv.BpWL.O08.UVs5lr+bwqkuPUU3t.v9lKBY5C.j0B.XfqkM
4AA.dqG.bVK.f7.ON.vctoXBc4XWmh4tZ.VQU3t.vNyBv.eKzCkCya0.rhpv
1GKh+pCDg3uz.Qv1tUNYSpiCcK73Vpd5sd8zcwAbwcRxdmzSEni.R.8EAPpL
+frhPUw6lEhB7L1RFFueHGZwHG.sa1by6koqmkCtLJAOO9uID281BDrTbDx8
sPEQ+drz2rgix65p.sFHaMVoKDVuoE9vvUGruhpvcwyB7r1sDQC96nmEXvpi
NRQU3t.vnYAX.4ACvq91UopJbW.X3rTDdXKviDfQ9qlhPQU3t.vfYAXBxxy+
QBvqN3CUUgECvuFkTdaxl8lq5VuqTv16S8UwtqdmQ6tGquljdJnpCb1Brlb8
6UZEdOy8KUlRt4luoAwGSNY.rUE3qcpwwYYFs2j+XH702aSkvvox616Z67tH
fcEvNsit1hVtqsbyOv8z0Von5B8KXGQU3huoFPf28MfAon5BcFXOQ0EeKT.d
tOHa0E5Avdhp3EipDGkD8Eipkazc6NbO+xPB16ZTIWe0ONDhCAX6iJcJoZqg
Qd27dYitosF8JVqbE6.2whT1WsOGNGYgkMVP5uVf2VXazT0j.br7KOGDh4.B
1Ai4CHt98U5njDtpbNIMefVbLHOXxdnFFwN28vRMXSTexL3krjnhbJWfeuB.
9aw4oIG9mexdKH8TFz5TxGW1.TteUrHZ2VjpPc+MVbMvxKiQKOS+ZTpEC2NV
tzlDmyGgNjwGjnc66aegtZX4bQd6Fqyw1da6ZcwGZER9XVgK101FgvXyg06H
qYObAOOtIJoAJRoCZFDFU0LvQMSoVPqUyeXXOpKRC9LOYxjxdZwgltR3kmy3
7SgAQMk5XOp7ORhZz.qQkTjQOlkew7arbMnrmK+2TPnTwNmv8KK6PFMrwDpx
0U6wcWvwfy4BGLRaFFEHiGKR6lHNQBOmb4Yj3GS6vRjYnTMr7vjHdH.cVHlA
ou8h4zlPXW+ZYfEWlcMo7vfv24cN6+1d4Vf5Iw17kprA.GAh5oLgMUPQdBmO
gEJsT97fTwHKeHNKMT5PbQL6+THQAOKC13C1zzyBundVCcJyyBgttmZoqzFx
ZfgDaBafdHxnRGBGRrpuvDIbVIM9MVbmUyGuZ1rL3fmaitkCmiNkUQQVdHkO
Hec5TEpqlNUSmpoS0zoZ5zRJRvMPmBzzoZ5TMcplNUSmNlNMHH8LRApTo0SS
ipoQ0znZZTMMJTQZTcv8ZZTMMplFUSiJjFEnHMpNndMMplFUSipoQmPi1tq7
pPkd05poS0zoZ5TMc5eToSG9PNYftgmHJC8cKUSnpIT0DpZBUo6gO5F1CeMc
plNUSmpoS+CCcZaASSSX0snYYNBbbdPs5cOHpoG58BZjkTjF11sco.tdJn4Q
ZVNKt2Dlt2YOiq9xfndORTpC2t9yUk9qJ2EtU8nuYeygqqgcYHP1w9lrXDYZ
ZsBPpRQmHjS86.Y+i7qR4GnxyMIEWhr1FEChUBJcuplAbbDj0GpyRN.Gjjx1
F42cKjeemouien5zroP4uprsQ982.4GB8l91zsOxORIweLizH4WnINe5a06s
FBTm2P6ejWc1mzywBONYUVVzkNJI8HMsxQwMRWmkC.3uYjNpgsiLf5zX6sPB
.ag0Iez8AM6BoD6FhrcCYpsRnmjwLu8SDjY13tah.1VhH3reh.PhHP1OQ.JQ
D72MQvEKQDv6mHPtmrXpIBNRDAv9IBtRDA39IBxnlPagHnTfIvsKvDjRdWAm
y6PjfL.QclzQnmiUksIx+XJRIxu+LdGRDjqEZyDPdRJaajek7eXrWFikeGfb
4WjuEan7CuECVY1ObeVmlUFvMQGIJxI7VEcDYS7eyG7nhtff1.4GAgV6mDS1
BIlfq+q2wtHwaQDzHOxNhwaQLyUYY88RhcUJNDxL7f9tBRpzM7f90I4kgGUy
wHb961ww3pjEO45qQggNBxH40ZSyH0nip0s9GsMZiiRZyLyF3FNxzFT88tXz
Q0ZSyrnMTaTZt8XNKUt6LsxO4h1rMRrRtHRPyv36I3OgDMRLr+Lk1iZv+5UJ
Di+M2Z9fym+fll0HO0Jh4ofelTG.+y0GyhqOtNwEZlR+f0dI0ItPyfzv2Y4z
v1cvy7Kml79T0eYYRiKXsAeTBkkccUdXpbeEyNGTCZU4qou+MdE9+qypUK.
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an exact answer without knowing what your USB device outputs, however in your patch whatever exits the [hi] object goes into the [live.text] button, which is set to Button mode, always converting it to a bang.

In the patch below I set the [live.text] button to Toggle mode. I also took the liberty of cleaning some other things up.

The next thing though is that you will need to find out what part of the output of the hi object is the information you are looking for. You can do that with a [print] object. Then you can select that number with an [unpack] and select the 1's and use that to trigger [random] (see the patch below).

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
1559.3oc6Z0ziiZCF9bxuBDmmF4O3ypdpWpZu11SqVE4P7Lw6BXpwjYFsZ+u
WaCjPBDvIgY6glLRCAaiseedd+zjusbg6F9azRWme14SNKV7skKVXZR2vhl6
W3lQdKIkTZFlaBOKilKceptOI8Moo8ew4YV9VG4NpSdU1FpvgkatKkUJUegH
cJekIS1QKc1PkuRo4N.Gh5QfsyUgfVplZhjwyWmxxoI7pbyriZFgZlY4oToY
q.aZjs0rA3a9xOAAtGGIuR1NTP6JPTa.V9KqEzDYsTiBvq.O4.AlKXXj9BBr
B37Y8y78kK0+6IKQmb5qp8QOvoPvNBYSIDwWuLfTadef5CDCgX.BFeThPFAB
MuBTUdAI4qJBT8msxUzvxEto05ljuWPqEJWCjcxEmOeYL.FFrJV+IDDFiCQd
f.EFfhWgMshiQ.LJ.hdxIL7tPjKa.jriyKo055M1.6nBps3S3Mq6hA8kRTTv
GglbIM8nA6IRDpuD4MrDgtDiugj+hlqGknQ.+AH5HCoh89HT1kNrAcQ0U4CZ
V3HCenT57a2EVx8ngQJ3.Ka21GzlYbvynUfqAJX7GCbAsDt7CuQ3B9CFt.Gz
qtC3pR41npciumHxIYz9cvjzr5w+azbpfk33372+4u537G72KkLkSWGacn.O
DIofHTKljJVSyIaRocefqya7jlmP.nu4oxAkVcqg16xzkj8zsqIRofsoRRO9
sxFjrAJ0HVZEk+bayssepvUk0rcA5MJ7vN8jgkxyeYPv+jQkoHuN3zI8UtiK
jSOEsvGptKi9R6kqT4IiVVRdg1yXqqpyTtig9ia1ziyG21P48v+7jNB75GIB
+g3kYGyVy.7UFERmv5zp4CktwPReWuaymz+Elb0qp7s4u5TjRdWuk2xJKlNS
Z73dlQvUQfy3TuXi0afwGnW703lFAFG6s1QskYFX7VG3aT3fH7co2kx1SWY.
7AbY2qyKFoa.0j3n9pId0Aj8uFzEFYi+cofjWxZQXz7vG2XVZCYfLfj+QETP
MZndmqthrHzv4j7MFdXzoYFCQLRF6.6Kw9RJxJ6HC0EFEo9uuen1qFDbLAN7
E0cGpx.z+ANFPgAyPQBOqzQTZTSY2GVmwiIkQePu7ddlKxHlAGXaXL+wr1Ay
mcsARsAN8vmKbymVqxo0VdlCDXIP6aRsLHnGPOklH16GasDHsmtS2o2.poi+
2F32hhs5ESGqgMym.e+.eHHFqMLLG9ENBzA+R47htxs9dAsP4f6rhHFOVU30
q7hmfA1JHuJ4lkv8RjhBmVqryDr2ZKdYKKQOQDw6GYK0iUTIWqU9pDzoNzkl
ZBCF.A8gpv851PHOEV6E34oc6zMmosDI47nXIorhCGBa2vXKbIaJ4opHepMx
Nin964RAe8e8J6EhHqDsJiu+PbEkaEVJ8PfmoG5WUoPVWFAeOipaoy.ZnuJP
jNKe+Pbm9NSqvHD7bohlVWpXJ5g.xcjktLV2hKpCjySaTWOhUlNDMyV+dR3o
Jmn7ssbMQ7xlSmzpb1+T0z8oOqxXkJJNzSaGMgeasDmfJXF7UeKUUX9nTwzC
0JpHvSqc4G8fJFkJf1SEvakJhBLTQ7CpXPpfPDE3oogKMLqn.jef18K3AEbQ
J.YGEbyNj7hMT.7AEbQJ.ZGEbyNhv.sin.zCJXPJnM8GKngwFpcwDPFqA7Cp
XzjVcv1m0pyMGcvGqq5Iv6AYLZtRX6yU5lohvProNo+eQEMMdxY4YlBW8Auc
1O5FSgl51Osn+RdkHoc607xLb5TLIsTxxOTY7mN7CHoyX3hsTgol1AOmAaW3
H0jBmXgMmHsykNQi4TDiFVDg20B6YwBi8lAI7.NM5RMGqDxh0Qe1L28BoOP2
I0OPyA1YgDglKAZRnaNT28sQWXNDIrUJ39yjI7jNKN0MUFaaAW4TswuHLdnW
bVP+WeTj+pPuabb0+9WfPvJu3A55d0Tis.EvygIQnMpp52E68uT1nr1WlpC6
QJJ1SEkMC1rFtYjuvMttidxbKKu9VyAv5Jn6YsiutEhHYGSRSZOnV22BpO.e
WcbbQdEqINfR5VpOYURYoNclxBRsfXNX8kee4+Jwi4ZG
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```